# Google GCM not returning error code "NotRegistered" when app was uninstalled

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am currently using GCM to notify 500 000 unique android users from my third party server. Everything is going fine for months. It appears that some users are uninstalling my app and gcm service doesn't tell me that the current user is not anymore using the app whith ["NotRegistered" error code](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html#response).

For example:

1. I install the app, and send the gcm_id to my third party server
2. I uninstall the app
3. I try to send a event to the app through gcm from my third party server :

> ```
> {
>   "collapse_key" : "collapse_key_1",
>   "data" : {
>       "EVENT" : "{\"myKey\":\"myValue\"}"
>   },
>   "time_to_live" : 30,
>   "registration_ids" : ["APA91bFvdRWZimIXJMmIXvss1D-jRPQEg-1bTJ7w9LwOPNzMkSdI0UojnIjxkY8FMamrTUyBecZ2a44u1Fy1qKmcnSQLpxi2Nmw5hBUJdECXmh1jOXMW5dcXFF0OEdVLBvTLPro9ToxqrWsmq5GhtKP0BV1-HQOAQ"]
> }
> ```

and get the response:

```
{
    "multicast_id" : 5965047050545487565,
    "success" : 1,
    "failure" : 0,
    "canonical_ids" : 0,
    "results" : [{
            "message_id" : "0:1428954436986778%d127aaafb324bdbf"
        }
    ]
}
```

I should receive a failure message (with NotRegistered code) from gcm because I uninstalled the app.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a success the first time after a GCM-enabled app has been uninstalled. It is during this turn that the client informs the GCM server that the client app was uninstalled. The server will then mark this particular registration ID for deletion.

It might take a while for the deletion from the GCM server, but later messages will eventually return *NotRegistered*. Refer to [this section](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#unreg-how) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

When the GCM server attempts to send the message to the device after the app has been uninstalled, the GCM client detects that this app is not longer installed on the device. You don't do it in your application code. The GCM client component of the Android OS does it.

The next time to try to send a message to the app on the device that uninstalled it, the GCM server will already know it has been uninstalled, and send you the NotRegistered error.

There is no lifecycle method called when the app is removed from the device. If there was, you wouldn't need the sequence of events you quoted above in order for the GCM server and the 3rd party server to detect that the app was uninstalled (since you could have used such a method to both unregister your app from the GCM server and to let the 3rd party server know the app was uninstalled from that device).